# Track, log 500 errors VUE NUXT

Tags: vue.js, error-handling, nuxt.js

So made my app in NUXT en django rest framework. When django would make a 500 error it will send mail_admin() and I'll get notified that something is wrong.

But when nuxt has a 500 error you will a nice 500 error page but I don't get informed about the error. There might be some logging in pm2. But I would not be aware.

So what is the correct strategy. I have been thinking to post the 500 error with Axios to django and let django mail me about it. But then I'm afraid I'll could create an infinite loop if there is an error in that process. (not likely)

So my question.
**What is the correct strategy to keep track of 500 errors and maybe 404 urls?**
Keep track so I'm informed something bad is going on and know what url and error message.

As I really don't find any source on this topic, this must be something so easy :/

Answer (score 0):

Posting to your backend would by far be the easiest way to handle this.  However, it's up to you to implement some kind of rate-limiting or queueing to prevent a massive influx of errors.  I have done this in a production setting when we needed some quick validation that our features were working, but didn't have time to pick up a more involved solution.

If you need more comprehensive tracking, you might want to pick up a service like [Rollbar](https://rollbar.com/).  Their free tier gives you up to 5000 errors reported to their service, and they can automatically email you for new occurrences.

The project I'm working on now uses this and it's been fantastic.  It can be configured to catch all uncaught errors, which can help uncover some issues that may not necessarily trigger the Nuxt error page.